# send data via Broadcast Receiver- crashes on Can't create handler inside thread

Tags: android, multithreading, broadcastreceiver

I'm pretty new in Android so please be patient with me:)

I'm trying to send data via Broadcast Receiver from a Parser Activity to a UI activity, where I'd like to show the data.

When I run my app, it crashes on "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()"

I put my code here so you can help me.

Many thanks
:)

```
      public class HandlePush extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    Button mButton;
    TextView mSignal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.handlepush);

        mSignal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TodaySigTV);


        registerReceiver(myBroadCastReceiver, new IntentFilter("my.action.string"));

        mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SignalButton);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Get a Tracker (should auto-report)
        ((AppManager) getApplication()).getTracker(AppManager.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
    }//oncreate



    private BroadcastReceiver myBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
            if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
                String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
                mSignal.setText(state);

            }
        }

    };


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();

        //Get an Analytics tracker to report app starts & uncaught exceptions etc.
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStart(this);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();

        //Stop the analytics tracking
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).reportActivityStop(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Contact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

}//handlepush


public class HistoryParser extends Activity{
// We don't use namespaces
        private final String ns = null;
        HistoryItems mObject;
        List<HistoryItems>mList;


        public List<HistoryItems> parse(InputStream inputStream) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            try {
                XmlPullParser parser = Xml.newPullParser();
                parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
                parser.setInput(inputStream, null);
                parser.nextTag();
                return readFeed(parser);
            } finally {
                inputStream.close();
            }
        }


        private List<HistoryItems> readFeed(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            List<HistoryItems> entries = new ArrayList<HistoryItems>();

            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "rss");
            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                // Starts by looking for the entry tag
                if (name.equals("item")) {
                    entries.add(readEntry(parser));
                } else {
                    //                  skip(parser);
                }
            }  
            return entries;
        }


        private HistoryItems readEntry(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "item");
            String title = null;
            String dateStr = null;

            while (parser.next() != XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    continue;
                }
                String name = parser.getName();
                if (name.equals("title")) {
                    title = readTitle(parser);
                //  sendData(title);////send the data from here
                } else if (name.equals("pubDate")) {
                    dateStr = readDate(parser);

                } else {
                    skip(parser);
                }
            } 
        //  sendData(title);////send the data from here
            return new HistoryItems(title, dateStr);

        }

        private String readTitle(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "title");
            String title = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "title");
            sendData(title);////send the data from here
            return title;
        }

        private String readDate(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException{
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.START_TAG, ns, "pubDate");
            String date = readText(parser);
            parser.require(XmlPullParser.END_TAG, ns, "pubDate");
            return date;
        }

        // For the tags title and link, extract their text values.
        private String readText(XmlPullParser parser) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
            String result = "";
            if (parser.next() == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                result = parser.getText();
                parser.nextTag();
            }
            return result;
        }

        private void skip(XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
            int depth = 1;
            while (depth != 0) {
                switch (parser.next()) {
                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    depth--;
                    break;
                case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                    depth++;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public void sendData(String title){

        Intent intent = new Intent("my.action.string");
        intent.putExtra("extra", title); // extra is the sent title
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
```

}//HistoryParser

10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at android.os.Handler.(Handler.java:121)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at android.app.Activity.(Activity.java:749)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.HistoryParser.(HistoryParser.java:17)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.HistoryAct$LongOperation.doInBackground(HistoryAct.java:64)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at com.Signals4Trading.push.android.HistoryAct$LongOperation.doInBackground(HistoryAct.java:1)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-14 11:23:10.297: E/AndroidRuntime(7674):     ... 5 more

Comment: Why did you create broadcast inside asynctask?

Comment: implement callback interface into activity and put your broadcast code inside callback function and call that interface from on post method of async..

Answer (score 0):

You cant put the Broadcast Receiver inside AsynTask. The BroadCastReciver should be in the activity and in onCreate you should register the reiver and the action, like this:

registerreceiver(yourReceiver, new IntentFilter(yourAction));

Hope it helps you!!

EDIT:

You should declare your broadcast receiver in the activity (outside the AsynTask) like an attribute. Something like this:

```
private BroadcastReceiver myBroadCastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String action = intent.getAction();
                Log.i("Receiver", "Broadcast received: " + action);
                if(action.equals("my.action.string")){
                    String state = intent.getExtras().getString("extra");
                    mSignal.setText(state);

                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Hi Alejandro,
Many many thanks for your help!
I’ve tried what you wrote and I certainly did not understand you correctly (which is very very possible) . Please see what I wrote, I edit a new code in my question

Comment: I've eidted my answer. You continuing declaring your BroadCast within Asyntask.

Comment: @Alejandro - why should BroadCastReceiver be in the activity?

Comment: Why not? The question is Why should BroadCastReceiver be in the AsynTask? this is not correct.

Comment: Oh Thanks Alejandro, I've tried this too (please refer to my edited code) but it crashes again. Maybe you need to see my logCat, right? I can't upload a picture because I need 10 credit (better reputation or something), what should be the better way for me to show you the logCat?

Comment: The reason that crash is beacuse you declare your receiver like a class (in my answer is declared like an attribute). Make this two changes and it should work correctly.

Comment: Oh right! Please see my edited code. Unfortunately, it crashes again... How can I share with you my logCat? I think it may help us a lot

Comment: ok I uploaded the error from my LogCat. Please Alejandro, have a quick look:)

Comment: The problem is in the AsynTask not in the BroadcastReceiver, the receiver should work correctly. Delete the AsynTask beacuse the task does nothing.

Comment: Ok, Please see my edited code. I delete the Asyntask because it really did nothing, as you said, I run again my app and It crashed again.